# Method object with generics for return type?

Tags: java, generics

Is there any way to use generics with the [Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) class in Java? I want to call [invoke()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)) on the Method object and have it return the actual return type of the method instead of [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).

Comment: Well, the return type of invoke() is Object, and there is no way to change that except by replacing Brian Goetz at the head of the JDK development team and decide to change it in Java 9. You can't change a method in Java. There is no way to make a non-generic method generic.

Comment: @JBNizet Can you please post that as answer since  there is no other choice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot extend `Method` because, although it is not `final`, it does not have an accessible constructor.

You can do something like this using composition instead.

```
public final class MyMethod<T> {

    private final Method method;

    public MyMethod(Method method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    public T invoke(Object o, Object... args) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        return (T) method.invoke(o, args);      // Unchecked cast
    }
}
```

You can use it like this

```
MyMethod<Integer> myMethod = new MyMethod<>(BigInteger.class.getMethod("intValue"));
Integer a = myMethod.invoke(new BigInteger("42"));
```

However, this is not nice (e.g. the unchecked cast and the checked exceptions).

I suspect this is an XY problem. Some details about what exactly you need this for would make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

As JB Nizet said you cannot change a JRE method, but you can do stuff, before the execution, after the execution, or around the execution, and you can change the returned value / Object returned by a method with AOP technologie like aspectJ, spring aop, google it it will be your friend